# Find a function with integral bounded from below and with prescribed properties

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space such that $\mu(X)<\infty$. Moreover assume that for any $i=1,\ldots, N$ the function  $f_i:X\to [0,+\infty[$ is  measurable  and such that
$$
\int_X f_id\mu>C
$$

for a fixed real contant $C$. Is it possible to find a measurable function $f:X\to [0,+\infty[$  satisfying the following properties (at the same time)?

- $f(x)\le f_i(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and any $i=1,\ldots, N$
- $\int_X f d\mu>C$

Comment: Is $f$ the limit of the $f_i$ ?

Comment: Would not the functions
$$
f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}
\qquad
f_n(x) = 1 + \frac 1 n 
$$
work with
$$
f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}
\qquad
f(x) = 1
$$
with $C=0$?

Comment: the $f_n$ are finitely many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $N=2$, $C=1$, $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be the probability space $([0,1], \mathscr{B}, \lambda)$, and define
$$
f_1:=3\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \quad \text{ and }\quad f_2:=f_1:=3\chi_{(\frac{1}{2},1]}.
$$
If $f: X\to [0,\infty)$ satifies $f\le f_1$ and $f\le f_2$ then $f=0$. However, it is false that $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu>1$.